# Regular expression for delete inline styles

Tags: css, regex

I have this regular expression for delete inline styles:

```
(style=").*"
```

I have 2 problems. Example:

```
<p style="margin:0pt; line-height:115%; font-size:11pt">
```

In this case all is fine, but I need select the space before P

Problem 2, If there are, more html tags in the same line, the expression doesn't work, and removes the "TEXT VERY IMPORTANT". Example:

```
<p style="margin:0pt; line-height:115%; font-size:11pt">TEXT VERY IMPORTANT 1 <p style="margin:0pt; line-height:115%; font-size:11pt">TEXT VERY IMPORTANT 2 <p style="margin:0pt; line-height:115%; font-size:11pt">TEXT VERY IMPORTANT 3
```

I need select only SPACE+style="..." (for then remove it)
Any help? Thank you.

Comment: Use an html parser, not regular expressions.

Comment: It's almost like [parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761).

Answer (score 0):

HTML is structured data that regex doesn't understand, which means you run into exactly the sort of issues you're having: for any non-trivial problem, the many allowed variations in the format make it very [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761) to parse using string manipulation techniques.

DOM methods are designed for manipulating that sort of data, so use them instead. The following code should be self-explanatory:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(el) { 
    el.removeAttribute("style")
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This regular expression for remove all attributes, solves my problem. (I have only 1 attribute).

```
((?<=<p))[^>]*(?=>)
```

Comment: This regex is invalid, you use groups where not nessesary and it looks like your intention is to remove all attributes.